# Apply Coupon Code While Programmatically Adding Product to Cart In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i want to apply coupon automatically after adding to cart.
Apply Coupon Code While Programmatically Adding Product to Cart In Magento 2

How can i acheive this one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using following code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Addtocart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $productrepository;
 protected $cart;
 protected $formKey;
 
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productrepository,
     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
 )
 {
     $this->cart = $cart;
     $this->productrepository = $productrepository;
     $this->formKey = $formKey;
     parent::__construct($context);
 }
 
 public function execute()
 {
     try {
         $productId = 1;
         $qty = 4;
         $coupancode = "abccoupon";
         $product = $this->productrepository->getById($productId);
         $formKey = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
         $paramater = array(
             'product' => $productId,
             'qty' => $qty,
             'form_key' => $formKey,
         );
         $this->cart->addProduct($product, $paramater);
         $this->cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($coupancode);
         $this->cart->save();
         return true;
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         return __($e->getMessage());
     }
 }
}
```

Another way using Object Manager applying coupon code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$couponCode = 'your_coupon_code';
$quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)
                                  ->collectTotals()
                                  ->save();
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: where i have to add this code ?